# Tell Mathematica how to //Expand a function

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have a function DP that takes two arguments, that is linear in both, i.e. DP[a,b+c] = DP[a,b] + DP[a,c]. I am using the following:

```
SetAttributes[DP, Orderless]
DP[a_?NumericQ x_, b_?NumericQ y_] := a b DP[x, y];
DP[a_?NumericQ x_, y_] := a DP[x, y];
Format[DP[i_,j_],StandardForm]:= (i\[CenterDot]j);
```

This displayed the function as required, i.e. `DP[a,b+c] = a.(b+c)`, however I would like to tell Mathematica how to act when I use `Expand[DP[a,b+c]]`.

I can write my own function to do this, e.g.

```
DPExpand[f_]:= f//.DP[a__,b__]:> Sum[DP[MonomialList[a][[k]],MonomialList[b][[j]]],{k,1,Length[MonomialList[a]]},{j,1,Length[MonomialList[b]]}].
```

However, I would really like this to just be part of `Expand[f]` too. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: One possibility would be to place an up Value on `DP`. `DP /: Expand[DP[a___, b_Plus, c___]] := Map[DP[a, #, c] &, b]

Expand[DP[a, b + c]]`

Comment: Never use upper-case letters to start the name of any variable or function, as it can conflict with internal function names.  This is especially true of `D`, as the derivative operator has a number of variants.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use [**`Distribute`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute.html?v=13.2) instead of [**`Expand`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expand.html?v=13.2).

For the example described in the OP

```
Distribute[DP[a, b + c]]
```

> [image: dist]

and another one

```
Distribute[DP[a + b, c + d]]
```

> [image: 2]

Note that the above are equivalent to `DPExpand[DP[a, b + c]]` and `DPExpand[DP[a + b, c + d]]` as they should.

Comment: Ahh, thanks this helps a lot. One issue, however, is that Distribute doesn't seem to work if I define 
```DP[a_?NumericQ x_, b_?NumericQ y_] := a b DP[x, y];
DP[a_?NumericQ x_, y_] := a DP[x, y];```

Any idea how I can work around this?

Comment: @Akoben hi, thanks for the comment. Not sure how you mean that. I used the exact definitions, you used in your questions with `?NumericQ` included; please see [**`screenshot`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZBcx.png). Did you mean something else?